# Duplicate 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorLanguageVersionAttribute' attribute

Tags: c#, docker, jenkins, asp.net-core

I am working on net core application. I am building my application in jenkins using docker. My sample repository is at

> https://github.com/niranjan2020/JenkinsPipeLine

Below is my command to build the application.

```
docker build -t jenkinspipeline/jenkins -f Dockerfile .
```

Below is my .csproj.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
   <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>

  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.0.2105168" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

When I start build in jenkins I get the below error

> obj/Release/netcoreapp2.1/jenkins.RazorAssemblyInfo.cs(11,12): error
>   CS0579: Duplicate
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorLanguageVersionAttribute'
>   attribute [/app/jenkins.csproj]
>   obj/Release/netcoreapp2.1/jenkins.RazorAssemblyInfo.cs(12,12): error
>   CS0579: Duplicate
>   'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorConfigurationNameAttribute'
>   attribute [/app/jenkins.csproj] The command '/bin/sh -c dotnet publish
>   -c Release -o output' returned a non-zero code: 1

What I tried so far is,

Deleted bin and object folder and rebuild-ed.
Added GenerateAssemblyInfo as false in .csproj
Restarted Jenkins

I added below configuration as per

> https://johnkoerner.com/csharp/dealing-with-duplicate-attribute-errors-in-net-core/

```
<GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyDescriptionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
```

This also dint work for me.
Below is my Jenkins.RazorAssemblyInfo.cs file which I commented and tried but dint work out.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

[assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationParts.RelatedAssemblyAttribute("Jenkins.Views")]
[assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorLanguageVersionAttribute("2.1")]
[assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorConfigurationNameAttribute("MVC-2.1")]
[assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Hosting.RazorExtensionAssemblyNameAttribute("MVC-2.1", "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.Extensions")]

// Generated by the MSBuild WriteCodeFragment class.
```

Nothing worked for me. Can someone help me to figure out the issue? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues in your repository:

1. Clean up your project, there are multiple leve `Jenkins.sln and Jenkins.csproj` in your project. Remove useless content.
2. I made a test with your `JenkinsPipeLine\Jenkins\Jenkins`
3. For the dockerfile in `JenkinsPipeLine\Jenkins\Jenkins`, its image is wrong, your project target `netcoreapp2.1`, you image should be `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1`. And the dockerfile is

   ```
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.1 AS build-env
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY *.csproj ./
   RUN dotnet restore
   COPY . ./
   RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o output
   # Runtime image
   FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:2.1
   WORKDIR /app
   COPY --from=build-env /app/output .
   ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "jenkins.dll"]
   ```
4. Run the command `docker build -t jenkins -f Dockerfile .` from `JenkinsPipeLine\Jenkins\Jenkins`

Comment: Thanks Tao Zhou. I will make changes now

Comment: Also where I need to keep my .csproj and sln file and docker file? Currently I have path like JenkinsPipeLine/Jenkins/Jenkins/? So where it is best to keep files?

Comment: @Niranjan keep these files in `JenkinsPipeLine\Jenkins\Jenkins`.

Comment: Thanks. Dockerigone and gitignore also in sample right?

Comment: @Niranjan that's it.

Comment: after making all the changes when I build my application I get below error unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: CreateFile C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\Dockerfile: The system cannot find the file specified.  My jenkins looking for dockerfile at path  C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\Test\Dockerfile but mt dockerfile is at workspace\Test\Jenkins\Jenkins. I chnaged home directory to C:/Program Files (x86)/Jenkins\workspace/Test/Jenkins/Jenkins but same error.

Comment: @Niranjan You need to run command from `workspace\Test\Jenkins\Jenkins` folder

Comment: I changed my command to docker build -t workspace/test/jenkins/jenkins -f Dockerfile . and still same issue!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200148/discussion-between-niranjan-and-tao-zhou).